# How can I code the InputBar in the sidebar of my extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image: the question]

How can I code the input bar?

I've tried using the vscode.window.showInputBox(), but that's not what I want. I want it to be inside the sidebar of the extension. When I asked Copilot it says that the TreeView doesn't support InputBoxes. This is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as vscode from "vscode";

// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "cohere" is now active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        "cohere.helloWorld",
        async () => {
            let message = await vscode.window.showInputBox({
                prompt: "Enter your message",
            });
            axios
                .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/cohere", { message: message })
                .then(function (response) {
                    let output: string = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2);
                    console.log(output);
                    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(output);
                })
                .catch(function (error: any) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    );

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}
```

Comment: I haven't used GHC, but are you sure that chat window is part of a "view" at all? I suspect it's a builtin part of the VSC workbench.

Comment: What's the VSC workbench? I tried using TreeViews and Webviews but none of them have what I want.